# iPhone/iOS: Subclassing UITableViewCell two times --> cannot reference properties of parentclass in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to use UITableViewCells within my application which have an image, and that image is downloaded asynchronously. Too accomplish that and to make sure that I dont have to write the same code several times within my application I subclassed UITableViewCell like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIImageView* imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView* imageView;

@end
```

Everytime I need a Cell with an image I would like to subclass the ImageCell like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ImageCell.h"

@interface StoreCell : ImageCell {

    UILabel* streetAddress;
    UILabel* retailerName;
    UILabel* distance;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* streetAddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* retailerName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* distance;

@end
```

However this doesnt seem to work. Since StoreCell is subclassing ImageCell I cant reference the property "imageView" anymore within the InterfaceBuilder.

Am I missing something here? Is this subclassing-scheme I'm trying to accomplish not meant to be in Objective-C / iPhone OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to tell interface builder about it using IBOutlet ... so

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;
```